On point-polygon distance
Consider a simple (i.e. non self-intersecting) polygon $P$, not necessarily convex, identified by the vertices $V_1,\dots,V_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a given point.
Consider the point $p \in P$ which has minimum squared distance from $y$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{proj}_{P}(y)\triangleq \arg \min_{p\in P} \lVert y-p\rVert^2
\end{equation*}
Let $V_*$ be the vertex closest to $y$. I'm suspecting that $\mathrm{proj}_{P}(y)$ is a point that always falls over one of these two edges
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
E_{+}(\lambda)\triangleq (1-\lambda)V_{*}+\lambda V_{*+1} \qquad \lambda \in[0,1)\\
E_{-}(\lambda)\triangleq (1-\lambda)V_{*-1}+\lambda V_{*} \qquad \lambda \in[0,1)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where by convention $V_{n+1}\triangleq V_1$. Unfortunately, I'm not able to prove my conjecture.
Question
Is my conjecture true?

For a counterexample, consider a triangle with side lengths $5,8,5$ and let $y$ be the midpoint of the longest side.
